# Scrape data from dynamic table using Python & Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, dynamic-tables

I'm trying to scrape data from this URL : https://qmjhldraft.rinknet.com/results.htm?year=2018, but I can't seem to be even able to scrape one single name from the dynamic table.

Here's the code that I currently have :

```
from selenium import webdriver
PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('https://qmjhldraft.rinknet.com/results.htm?year=2018')
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ht-results-table"]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[4]').text
print(element)
```

The code gives me this error :

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="ht-results-table"]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[4]"}
```

There's obviously something wrong with my XPath, but I can't figure out what.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: What do you want to scrape, please be specific in what data you would like to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first problem is as if the website is loading dynamically you need to give some time to load the page fully. to solve it you can use this

```
time.sleep(2) 
// change the number according to your need.
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ht-results-table"]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[4]').text
```

the best way is using [Explicit Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits). this will wait for the element to load then execute the next step.

2nd problem is you shouldn't just copy the XPath from the chrome dev tools

to get all the names you can do this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('https://qmjhldraft.rinknet.com/results.htm?year=2018')

try:
    elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@rnid]/td[3]"))
    )
finally:
    names = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr[@rnid]/td[3]')

for name in names:
    nm = name.text
    print(nm)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: It works, and I understand why my code wasn't working, thanks a lot!!

Comment: So, why don't you accept the answer?

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow, and didn't that this way the way to thank other users / how to do it. I google'd it and now I did thank him. Thanks for the heads up